# PBKDF2 (php) produces different output than CryptoJS.PBKDF2 (js)

Tags: encryption, openssl, cryptojs, pbkdf2

As you can see below, my php implementation produces different key than JS version (running on Extend Script if that makes any difference). PHP side uses default hash_pbkdf2, JS side uses CryptoJS library. Both use SHA256.

Am I missing something here?

---

**PHP side**

```
$salt = CryptoLib::randomString(128/8);
$password = "test";
$hasher = "sha256";
$iterations = 1000;
$outsize = 256;

$key = hash_pbkdf2($hasher, $password, $salt, $iterations, $outsize/8, true);
$key = bin2hex($key);
```

***salt output:*** 523554455475374b5942304448317468

***key output:*** cfb478a18d08030fe97beed34fd2da3abf89bb7975ffdaae9e39102a3b2ea1a2

---

**JS side**

```
var salt = "523554455475374b5942304448317468";
var password = "test";
var iterations = 1000;
var keySize = 256;

var key = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(password, salt, {keySize: 256/32, iterations: 1000, hasher:CryptoJS.algo.SHA256});
```

***key output:*** 1264aa07aeab3cf93d4ee86a074697165efffe4914ce98e6d6efd7f28c371b97

Comment: You should probably use the [PBKDF2 Test Vectors](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6070.txt) to see if any of them are producing correct results.

Comment: The salt in the php implementation is always a random string and in the js you use a constant as a salt; you are just not providing the same inputs to the calculating functions. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Salt was generated once (523554455475374b5942304448317468) then taken to JS (sorry I should have pointed that out in the original post). Of course, if I re-run the PHP, if will create a new salt which will have to be imported to JS again.

Comment: I should also point out that PHP <-> PHP encryption/decryption works just fine and the generated key returns the same value (after decoding salt from string). So I believe it must be some implementation of CryptoJS which is probably expecting variables in a different format (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be a problem with ExtendScript. If you're using minified versions of CryptoJS, make sure you switch to full js versions because for some reason ExtendScript will generate different values:

Example:

**with minified Base64 CryptoJS module included:**

```
salt.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64) 
= ADAASDASHFDSFKSD/ASDAHSDJAGLDFblablabla
```

**with full Base64 CryptoJS module included:**

```
salt.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64)
= Zl0gFqZIc3CczOo/FBlNSn3NPAAsw=
```

Comment: I don't understand what Base64 has anything to do with your question. It rather looks like you forgot to decode the salt: `salt = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(salt)`.

Comment: I used Base64 as an example of producing different output when using ExtendScript with minified js version. It looks like it does the same with other enc functions as well, so therefore it produced different outputs. Both outputs (php and js) produced the same var after declaring the full versions instead of minified.